# Can't access class attribute after getChildAt()

Tags: android

Following Scenario:

I create a class 'exampleClass' with an inflated view. The class has an atribute `'String A'` with a corresponding getter.

I create an instance of this class. No surprise for me that i can call both `Log.v(LOG_TAG, instance.toString());` follwed by `Log.v(LOG_TAG, instance.getA());` which results in the right outputs.

I add this instance to a ViewGroup called container. Then i call `container.getChildAt(0).toString()`. That gives me as expected, the same output as above with `Log.v(LOG_TAG, instance.toString());`, no difference.

What's not working is to call `container.getChildAt(0).getSideA` (or any other member). Only methods that belong to the inflated view are available.

So is there a way to get access to attributes and members? Any other background information about this topic is also appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast target type to `container.getChildAt(0)` before using `getSideA` method.

```
((TargetClassType) container.getChildAt(0)).getSideA()
```

Comment: That's interesting: I already thought about casting. At first that didn't worked (Android Studio said casting is redundant but  no access though) . It was neccesary to store it a variable then it worked. May you add that information to your solution.